# Does Golang have an equivalent to Blob data type?

Tags: go, blob

I am uploading a file using a GoServer. I can convert the file to base64. After this I want to convert that to Blob (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).

In JS I would do this but cannot find an equivalent data type in GoLang.

> ```
> const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) => {
>
>  const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
>  const byteArrays = [];
>
>  for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
>    const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
>
>    const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
>    for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
>      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
>    }
>
>    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
>    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
>  }
>  const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType } );
>  return blob; 
> }
> ```

Comment: Perhaps `[]byte`

Comment: `[]byte` is not the same thing.. It could possibly be a struct with specific fields and a `[]byte`. The issue is if I am using JS with a native Blob datatype and then interacting with another language or tool with a native Blob datatype things run smooth.

If I give those tools an array of bytes it is not the same thing..

Comment: hi @wvb1, have you found the answer for this question? I'm also curious about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user-unknown `[]byte` it is.

Answer (score -1):

Check if, in the project [`realPy/hogosuru`](https://github.com/realPy/hogosuru), the [`blob` package](https://github.com/realPy/hogosuru/blob/a884b3dec6a0d0193975375a414ffcf4e2b29004/blob/blob.go) would implement what you need.

It does come with a [`BlobStream` struct](https://github.com/realPy/hogosuru/blob/a884b3dec6a0d0193975375a414ffcf4e2b29004/blob/blobstream.go)

```golang
type BlobStream struct {
    Blob
    cur        int64
    buffersize int64
    size       int64
}
```